# How to convert character timestamps in SAS to valid datetime values

Tags: datetime, sas, timestamp, character

I've two different character timestamps in SAS and need to convert them to datetime (24H) values.
What is the preferred way to achieve this?

**Sample 1**

```
01-12-2023 09:51 AM
24-08-2023 02:38 PM
```

Desired output:

```
01-12-2023 09:51:00
24-08-2023 14:38:00
```

My solution for Example 1 (not sure if this is the best)

```
PROC FORMAT;
    picture dmyhms
        . = ' ' 
        other = '%0d-%0m-%0Y %0H:%0M:%0S' (datatype=datetime);
RUN;

INPUT(CATX(" ", SUBSTR(event, 1, 10), SUBSTR(event, 12, 8)),anydtdtm.) FORMAT dmyhms. AS event_dt
```

**Sample 2**

```
20240112T000000.000 GMT
20230929T000000.000 GMT
```

Desired output:

```
12-01-2024
29-09-2023
```

My solution for Example 2 (not sure if this is the best)

```
INPUT(SUBSTR(event, 1, 8), yymmdd8.) FORMAT=ddmmyyd10. as event_d
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to read the first 10 characters of EVENT as being DD-MM-YYYY then use DDMMYY10. informat.  If you use any of the ANYDT.. series of informats with strings in that ambiguous style then make sure to set DATESTYLE option to DMY before hand so the informat knows you want to treat the first number as the DAY and not the MONTH.

Comment: You should get credit for the time you took to respond by creating an answer. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Sample 1:

```
data have;
   c_ts = '01-12-2023 09:51 AM'; output;
   c_ts = '24-08-2023 02:38 PM'; output;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   n_ts = input(c_ts, anydtdtm.);
   format n_ts datetime20.;
run;
```

Comment: If you are going to use ANYDT... series of informats with strings in either MDY or DMY style then make sure you have set the DATESTYLE option so it knows what you want to do with ambiguous values like the first string in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Sample 2, @Tom has offerred an easy and effective way:

```
data have;
   event = '20240112T000000.000 GMT'; output;
   event = '20230929T000000.000 GMT'; output;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   event_d = input(event, yymmdd8.);
   format event_d ddmmyyd10.;
run;
```